# How to setup Gogs as a local github cache for "go get"

Tags: git, go, github, gogs

I have a Gogs server setup and running with PostgreSQL. I have also  mirrored a public repo from github by using the Gogs web interface.

Now I'm wondering can I make the commandline `go get` use the Gogs server as a proxy for getting packages? ie. I want the command like `https_proxy=http://gogs_server:3000 go get -u github.com/user/repo` to download the mirror repo from the local Gogs server instead of actually going out to github.com to download it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that, you would most likely have to create some kind of customized HTTP proxy to rewrite GitHub URLs to point to your Gogs instance, and then stick that in between `go get` and the Internet.

However, if you're just looking to cache packages locally for better performance (or better reliability), it's recommended to keep them in the [`vendor` directory](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Vendor_Directories). That way, they can't unexpectedly vanish, and are kept in source control with the rest of your code.

Comment: +1 thanks for the vendor directory note. My project gets built & run inside a docker container using the basic instructions from https://hub.docker.com/_/golang/ so it downloads all dependencies from github each time its built. the vendor dir sounds like it could prevent all those downloads from happening.